# Is it *possible* to make your own Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a project where our tab bar has a big middle button (that extends above the tab bar) and other custom behaviors including a badge icon and colored labels.

I got "smart" and decided to just write my own tab bar and tab bar controller to go with it. The problem I've run into is that when one of the tabs is wrapped in a UINavigationController, that view always takes up the whole screen (you can't capture a UINavigationController into a small subview) and so I have to manually inset the content on those views.

Is there a smart way to handle this? It feels gross to just cut the content short on each screen by 100 points...that doesn't feel right at all.

What approach should I take...or should I just automate the content insets programmatically?

Comment: "(you can't capture a UINavigationController into a small subview)" Actually yes you can. Programatically just create UINAvigationController and add its view anywhere in your customtabbar and setup any frame as you need (preffer autolayout of course). Or in storyboard you can use embeded UIView item.

Comment: The content will always display full screen. You can't specify a rectangle of space for a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

A tab bar controller is just a scroll view with a view at the bottom that toggles between the scroll view's offset. I assume you want the tab bar controller to be at the root of your app, so in the root view controller, add a `UIScrollView`.

Then add the views of the view controllers (the tabs) to that scroll view, and anchor them appropriately so that the scroll view scrolls. Make the heights and widths of these view controllers full screen. Before you add them to the scroll view, you must create a parent-child relationship between the root view controller and its tabs.

```
self.addChildViewController(tabOneViewController)
tabOneViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
scrollView.addSubview(tabOneViewController.view)
tabOneViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
tabOneViewController.delegate = self // so that your tabs can communicate back to the controller
// add constraints
```

Each of these view controllers will ideally be or contain the navigation controller for that section.

Then just add the tab bar to the `view` of the view controller, not to the scroll view (add this after the scroll view so that it sits above the scroll view). This tab bar is just a regular `UIView`, most often anchored to the view controller's bottom safe area. Because its a part of the view controller's view, and not the scroll view, it has no impact on the content behind it.

The benefit of a custom tab bar setup like this is that you can navigate between tabs on tap or by pan gesture. To navigate between tabs by tapping on the buttons in the tab bar, simply change the scroll view's content offset:

```
// this would move to the third tab
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width * 2, y: 0)
```

Add your bells and whistles and you're set.